# Why does the matrix field produce such a massive amount of duplicate information?

Tags: matrix, database

[image: Large amount of duplication the matrix field is producing]

The matrix field in Craft CMS is producing massive quantities of duplicate data. About 70 database rows per entry. Is there something I'm doing wrong? I don't think this will be sustainable for my database. The image embedded displays a fraction of the entries into the matrix table for a single Craft CMS structure entry.

Using Craft Pro 3.6.12

Comment: Maybe those are just revisions / drafts?

Comment: Soft deletes too. Running `./craft gc` would probably get rid of some of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Oli, I ran `./craft gc` for garbage collection. The matrix field went from 70+ (sometimes as much as 130) rows to 8. Still a terribly non-normalized database table, but much better than 70 records for one entry.

Thanks to Oli!